# TypeScript define AMD module by parts

Tags: typescript, amd

Is it any way to split definition of AMD modules to several files?

Example what I mean:

```
// file WebApp/Deferred.ts
export module WebApp {
    export class Deferred {
        //...
    }
}

// file WebApp/Promise.ts
export module WebApp {
    export class Promise {
        //...
    }
}

// file init.ts
import WebApp = require("WebApp/Deferred", "WebApp/Promise"); // This is incorrect TS synatax
var a = new WebApp.Deferred();
```

Comment: Normally, you'll have a Deferred.ts with Deferred, Promise.ts with Promise, and a WebApp.ts which imports both, defines a namespaced object and exports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a supported pattern. I recommend you create an index.ts file inside `WebApp` and export the common stuff from there. Sample `index.ts`:

```
import deferred = require('./Deferred');
import promise = require('./Promise');
export var Deferred = deferred.WebApp.Deferred;
export var Promise = promise.WebApp.Promise;
```

So in your `init.ts`:

```
 import WebApp = require("WebApp/index");
 var a = new WebApp.Deferred();
```

This is a common pattern on node.js where people create an index.js file in a folder. In fact node.js provides a shorthand for the import statement and there is a related feature request for TypeScript : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2125

PS: I recommend not using `internal modules` when you are already using external modules (amd/commonjs). see : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1